# making subsubsections visible in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I'm trying to write a report, and I've defined that it defines 3 numbered levels (section, subsection & subsusection) using `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`. But how can I make these subsubsections visible in the TOC, please ? I can't find a solution to deal that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This consists in the use of `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`.